# Search for more than one account

Tags: linkedin-api

I would like to query that runs for more than one accounts. I tried below one but I got error. Also, I couldn't find a way for it.

How can I get accounts values in a one query?

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=statistics&pivots[0]=ACCOUNT&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.month=11&dateRange.start.year=2019&timeGranularity=MONTHLY&accounts[0]=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:1231231,1231233,123123123

Answer (score 0):

I found that by trying by myself. Adding account by accounts[0] and accounts[1] ...
can be gotten accounts from API

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=statistics&pivots[0]=ACCOUNT&dateRange.start.day='+startOfMonth.day()+'&dateRange.start.month='+startOfMonth.month()+'&dateRange.start.year='+startOfMonth.year()+'&timeGranularity=MONTHLY&accounts[0]=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:123123123&accounts[1]=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:12312313